# how to reverse a pandas series by index without changing values order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, series

now i have a pandas series looks like:

```
Date
2020-01-02    74.573036
2020-01-03    73.848030
2020-01-06    74.436470
2020-01-07    74.086395
2020-01-08    75.278160
2020-01-09    76.877136
2020-01-10    77.050926
2020-01-13    78.697075
2020-01-14    77.634407
2020-01-15    77.301704
2020-01-16    78.270020
2020-01-17    79.136551
2020-01-21    78.600250
2020-01-22    78.880821
2020-01-23    79.260696
2020-01-24    79.032265
2020-01-27    76.708298
2020-01-28    78.878326
2020-01-29    80.529434
2020-01-30    80.412743
2020-01-31    76.847343
2020-02-03    76.636299
2020-02-04    79.166336
2020-02-05    79.811897
2020-02-06    80.745445
2020-02-07    79.647896
2020-02-10    80.026192
2020-02-11    79.543365
2020-02-12    81.432350
2020-02-13    80.852463
2020-02-14    80.872375
2020-02-18    79.391556
2020-02-19    80.541367
2020-02-20    79.715088
2020-02-21    77.910744
2020-02-24    74.209946
2020-02-25    71.696297
2020-02-26    72.833664
2020-02-27    68.072662
2020-02-28    68.032837
```

how to reverse the whole series to let the latest date be on the first row without changing the orders of values? (let each index and value stick together)

Comment: Please accept the most correct answer if one of these answered your question

Answer (score 5):

Let `df` be your data :

```
df = df.to_frame().reset_index()
date_vals = df.Date.values
df['Date'] = date_vals[::-1]
```

Comment: This needs updated to work. The date is the index, so it won't be a column when converted with .to_frame() from a series. Therefore, you can't reference it with df.Date, but you need to access the index.

Comment: I see, then you can do `df.to_frame().reset_index()` which will give the date as a column value and proceed

Answer (score 3):

`ds` is your pandas series. You want to reverse the date index and keep the values with their date (index and values stick together) then you can do:

```
ds = ds[::-1]
# This is shorthand for taking all the dates but you can take specific dates like this
ds['2020-01-07':'2020-01-02':-1]
```

To reverse the date index but keep the data values in the same location you can do:

```
ds.index = ds.index.values[::-1]
```

to just reverse the data values but not the date index:

```
# Use this to update but sometimes I had issues using this
ds.update(ds.values[::-1])
# or you can do this instead and recreate the series if it doesn't work
ds = pd.Series(ds.values[::-1], ds.index)
```